# How to compare noun chunks in python with spacy.io

Tags: python, nlp, levenshtein-distance, spacy

I am trying to write a Python application which will take a natural language query and attempt to convert it into [Microsoft MDX queries for SQL-Server, to query a Cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-the-basic-query).

I am using spacy.io and I am having trouble figuring out the best way to compare noun chunks with the names of datasources/measures/filters/etc.

Example input sentence:

```
"Give me household count split by net sales from the base customer cube"
```

And from that I can extract the following noun chunks:

```
NP:  household count split
NP:  net sales
NP:  the base customer cube
```

What's the best way to compare those noun chunks to the following display names from my test cube?

```
Household Count
Net Sales
Base Customer
```

The trouble is one of the noun chunks contains the word "split", I can't just remove it in case one of the display names from the cube also contains that word.

I have thought about trying a few things, for example calculating the Levenstein distance between the strings but the results are not really reliable enough to declare a match.

So my question is how can I solve this and get more reliable matches? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Or perhaps not using Spacy.io to its full potential?

I have thought about parsing the noun chunks and removing key words like "split" and unnecessary words such as "the" before getting the Levenshtein distance, but I don't feel comfortable with providing a list of possible words to remove, in the case that there are some genuine display names which contain one of the keywords.

Comment: What's `MDX'? What's a "Cube"? spacy.io as in the SpaCy for `nlp`?

Comment: Did you by any chance find the answer to this question? I have been researching ways to translate natural language questions to MDX queries, so that I can extract information from dimensions as well...

I don't know about spacy, it kind of outperforms NLTK, which the NLTK seems also like a good option...

Am also wondering how you came up with your tree. There are several parsing tree, how did you find this one?

Comment: @lilienfa: 'MDX' seems to be [Microsoft SQL-Server jargon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/mdx-query-the-basic-query), specifically 'MultiDimensional Expression query' APIs, and '[data] cube' is merely OLAP jargon for '[big] database which we routinely query by multiple (3+) indices (typically date, customer_id and other stuff)' . Don't you just love it when people write questions in plain English, though? I remember those days wistfully...